# How to replace case-of or matching pattern with guards in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying (as a part of learning) replace case-of expression with expression with guards.
This is a function with case-of

```
myList :: [a] -> String
myList xs = case xs of []  -> "empty"
                       [x] -> "one"
                       xs  -> "more"
```

I've managed to write a function with where and matching pattern

```
myList' :: [a] -> String
myList' xs = someF xs 
where someF []  = "empty"
      someF [x] = "one"
      someF xs  = "more"
```

However, I could not make another function myList'' which is using guards (|).
I am new in Haskell, and would much appreciate if somebody can help me with this problem.
Thank you in advance.
Al

Comment: You can use *pattern guards*.

Comment: Note that, in the general case, using guards instead of pattern matching is a bad idea (I'm considering plain boolean guards here, not pattern guards). This is because guards force you to reduce a potentially richer value to a boolean, losing information in the process. Try translating `f :: [Int] -> Int ; f [] = 2 ; f (x:_) = x` using guards. You will need to use `null` which however on a non empty list only returns `False`, instead of `False, it starts with x` carrying the value we need. To get that `x` we then need to use partial (= dangerous) functions like `head` or `!!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of *pattern guards*, for example:

```
myList'' :: [a] -> String
myList'' xs
    | [] <- xs = "empty"
    | [_] <- xs = "one"
    | otherwise = "more"
```

Or you can make use of [**`null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) and [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop) to check if the list is empty:

```
myList'' :: [a] -> String
myList'' xs
    | null xs = "empty"
    | null (drop 1 xs) = "one"
    | otherwise = "more"
```

Comment: Thanks Willem! You helped me again. I could not figure it out, how to use patters in guards. Now, I understand. Thanks Again.

Comment: Using  null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool and drop :: Int -> [a] -> Bool and drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a] is also working, but this is what I was not even thinking yet to use. THANK YOU. That was quick and nice answer. Al

Comment: Willem, The last example of yours. It was a very smart approach. Great.